# No suitable method found for clone(Tuple)

Tags: java, debugging, methods

I need help debugging my program ChangeMaker.

```
    public class ChangeMaker {

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class ChangeMaker
 */
public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        for(int x = 1; x < coins; x++) {
        int coin = Integer.parseInt(args[x + 1]);

        for (int i = 1; i <= quantity; i++) {
            Tuple tuple = table[x][i];
            int amount = i;
            int leftover = amount % coin;
            int coinTotal= (int)Math.floor(amount / coin);

            if (leftover == 0) { 

                tuple.setElement(x, coinTotal);
                int bestRow = optimalCheck(table, tuple, x, i);

                Tuple bestTuple = table[bestRow][i];

                tuple.clone(bestTuple);


            } else if (leftover != 0 && amount < coin) { 

                tuple.clone(table[x - 1][i]);

            } else if (leftover != 0 && amount > coin) { 

                tuple.setElement(x, coinTotal);
                Tuple leftoverTuple = table[x][leftover];
                tuple.add(leftoverTuple);

                int bestRow = optimalCheck(table, tuple, x, i);
                Tuple bestTuple = table[bestRow][i];
                tuple.clone(bestTuple);
            }
        }
    }
```

Every time I try to call the .clone() method, there's an error saying that method java.lang.Object.clone is not applicable (actual and formal argument lists differ in length). Method Tuple.clone() is not applicable. However, when I comment out the clone methods every other method works such as the .add() and .setElement().

Here is the clone method:

```
public class Tuple
{
private  int[] tupleArray;
private int tupleLength;

    public Tuple clone () {
    Tuple copy = new Tuple(this.tupleLength);
    for(int i=0; i<this.tupleLength; i++) {
        copy.tupleArray[i]=this.getElement(i);
    }
    return copy;
}
```

Comment: you should have Tuple the implement Cloneable interface.